# How to navigate to record detail page using community builder?

Tags: community, community-builder

I have a community configured using napili template. Now my requirement is i need to redirect to the custom objects record detail page on click of the tab specified in navigation menu.
Presently when I select the Community page "Mypage" in navigation menu directly it gives following error.

> The URL for My Assessor Registration requires one or more parameters. Please replace each parameter with the appropriate value.

If I select the custom object in navigation menu it redirects to list view where when I click on record the detail page opens.

My requirement is directly I need to redirect to detail page of the record on click of tab specified in navigation menu.(This custom object is related to the contacts from which i have loged in as community user)

Answer (score 1):

You can use last option , redirect to external url and in that URL you can input your detail page URL with appropriate ID.

Edit

This is a dynamic link and not a static as per recent comnent.You will need a lightning component here and with CSS in head section you can pull and make link appear as any other navigation menu.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, this would not resolve it as i would not be able to give the record id hardheadedly. We specify :recordId where it gives an error as record id is not known

Comment: The url is configurable here ,so you can change any time .Can you sketch your use case ?If you want to open a detail object page i assume you know the record you will be displaying before hand.

Comment: I just want to confirm that can i fetch the related record of user contact and on click of navigation menu go to the detail page of that record.Please note that the record will be single but will totally depend on the users contact.

Comment: Ok so this is a dynamic link and not a static .You will need a lightning component here and with CSS in head section you can pull and make link appear as any other navigation menu.

Comment: Hmm Thanks, Yes but i wondered that there may be an option to do it with community builder directly

Comment: No ..you can open an idea but this is not OOB .